# How do I force a child div to be inside parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've started to learn JavaScript, and I'm trying to improve this script. I want to keep the generated box within the fixed parent div, so in different screen sizes it will force the clicked div to appear within the visible area.

```js
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
var clickedTime;
var createdTime;
var reactionTime;

function makeBox() {
  var rndm = Math.random();
  rndm = rndm * 1000;
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
      document.getElementById("box").style.borderRadius = "50%";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("box").style.borderRadius = "0px";
    }
    var top = Math.random();
    var left = Math.random();
    top = top * 340;
    left = left * 1000;
    document.getElementById("box").style.position = "absolute";
    document.getElementById("box").style.top = top + "px";
    document.getElementById("box").style.left = left + "px";
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
    document.getElementById("box").style.display = "block";
    createdTime = Date.now();
  }, rndm);
}
document.getElementById("box").onclick = function() {
  this.style.display = "none";
  clickedTime = Date.now();
  reactionTime = ((clickedTime - createdTime) / 1000);
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = reactionTime;
  makeBox();
}
makeBox();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: verdana, "comic sans ms", arial;
}
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
  position: relative;
}
.p {
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* setting the parent div size according to the device screen size */

#parent {
  position: fixed !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 150px;
  /*            background-color: aquamarine;*/
  border: 1px solid aqua;
  margin: 0px 3px 5px 5px;
}
#date {
  font-weight: normal !important;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 590px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Reaction Game</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Test Your Reaction</h1>
  <h3 id="date"> 
        </h3>
  <p class="p">Your Reaction Time <span id="user"></span> is : <span id="time"> 0 </span> Seconds.</p>
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="box"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I see that you override some css attributes like #parent position and #parent top. You should note that only `top: 150px;` and `position: fixed !important;` take effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes:

1. Changed parent `div` from `position: fixed` to `position: relative`.
2. Changed `top` and `left` values from `px` to `%`.
3. Added `div` with `main` class (added to this `div` `padding-bottom: 100px` and `padding-right: 100px;` to fit the shapes in your parent div if left or top equals to something like `100%`.
4. Added height to parent `div` (you can change the height for different devices using media queries).
5. Removed border from `#parent`, added to `.main`

```js
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

var clickedTime;
var createdTime;
var reactionTime;

function makeBox() {
  var rndm = Math.random();
  rndm = rndm * 1000;
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
      document.getElementById("box").style.borderRadius = "50%";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("box").style.borderRadius = "0px";
    }
    var top = Math.random();
    var left = Math.random();
    top = top * 100;
    left = left * 100;
    document.getElementById("box").style.position = "absolute";
    document.getElementById("box").style.top = top + "%";
    document.getElementById("box").style.left = left + "%";
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
    document.getElementById("box").style.display = "block";
    createdTime = Date.now();
  }, rndm);
}
document.getElementById("box").onclick = function() {
  this.style.display = "none";
  clickedTime = Date.now();
  reactionTime = ((clickedTime - createdTime) / 1000);
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = reactionTime;
  makeBox();
}
makeBox();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: verdana, "comic sans ms", arial;
}
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
  position: relative;
}
.p {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0px 3px 5px 5px;
}
#date {
  font-weight: normal !important;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 590px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.main {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  border: 1px solid aqua;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test Your Reaction</h1>
<h3 id="date"></h3>
<p class="p">Your Reaction Time <span id="user"></span> is : <span id="time">0 </span> Seconds.</p>
<div class="main">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```